# integrating E-mail feature in android app

Tags: android

I just started to develop my first android project.

I want to add a feature of sending email from my android app when a button is pressed.

Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Hoping for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String mail = "mailto:?to=emailaddress&subject="+subject+"&body="+body;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(mail));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send via..."));
```

just use the three lines to send mail

Answer (score 2):

It is really easy in android - you just need to start one Email intent. Please see [this](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/22/email-sending-in-android/) short tutorial. It is not the same as the one I followed once upon a time, when I implemented this feature, but seems simple and descriptive enough.